# Monit and multiple actions: chaining commands in Monit restart command?

Tags: configuration, service, monit

After some researches, it occurs that even if I can find some talks about *multiple actions* when restarting a service, it also seems it it not really possible to achieve :

```
 if failed port 80 and protocol http
     then exec /home/sweet/script.pl
     and restart
```

When declaring the restart command for a service in the `monitrc` configuration file, is it ok to try something like this :

```
restart program = "perl /home/sweet/crazy-stuff.pl && /etc/init.d/server restart"
```

As `monit -t` don't mention any error I prefer to ask before to do bad things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use exec and a bash subshell, for example:

```
exec "/bin/bash -c '/etc/init.d/server restart && perl /home/sweet/script.pl'"
```

However, best practice recommends using a single script for all your actions ( meaning include the init.d restart command into your shell script.)

Answer (score 0):

how about this format

```
  blabla... exec "/bin/sh -c 'foo=$(mktemp) && tee $foo <<-EOF
# create the bash script then execute it

/etc/init.d/server restart
perl /home/sweet/script.pl

# and any other commands as you wish

EOF
/bin/bash $foo'"
```

if you want auto delete, append `/bin/rm $foo` after `/bin/bash $foo`

```
...
EOF
/bin/bash $foo; /bin/rm $foo'"
```